# Stretch flex first row items equally other than last items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to show year items in center in the wrapper. With `.inn-wrap>* { flex: 1 1 auto; }` it is stretching the last two items inside the wrapper, is it possible if it can be done for the first two items rather than the last two.

This year list grows dynamically based on the blog for that year

```css
.wrap{ width:300px;margin:30px auto; background-color:#000; padding:15px; margin-bottom:20px;}
.inn-wrap{width:100%; 
display: flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content: center;
text-align:center;
}
/*for last row: column items */
.inn-wrap>* { flex: 1 1 auto; }
.year{display:inline-block; margin:5px 5px; padding:5px 15px; background-color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none; color:#000;font-size:16px; font-weight:600;
}
```

```html
<div  class="wrap">
   <div class="inn-wrap">
      <a href="/articles/2018" class="year">2018</a>
      <a href="/articles/2017" class="year">2017</a>
      <a href="/articles/2016" class="year">2016</a>
      <a href="/articles/2015" class="year">2015</a>
      <a href="/articles/2014" class="year">2014</a>
      <a href="/articles/2013" class="year">2013</a>
      <a href="/articles/2012" class="year">2012</a>
      <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2011</a>
      <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2010</a>
      <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2009</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvvgBd) link

another example with responsive width

```css
.wrap{ width:40%;margin:30px auto; background-color:#000; padding:15px; margin-bottom:20px;}
.inn-wrap{width:100%; 
display: flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content: center;
text-align:center;
}
/*for last row: column items */
.inn-wrap>* { flex: 1 1 auto; }

.year{display:inline-block; margin:5px 5px; padding:5px 15px; background-color:#fff;
            text-decoration:none; color:#000;font-size:16px; font-weight:600;
}
```

```html
<div  class="wrap">
   <div class="inn-wrap">
      <a href="/articles/2018" class="year">2018</a>
      <a href="/articles/2017" class="year">2017</a>
      <a href="/articles/2016" class="year">2016</a>
      <a href="/articles/2015" class="year">2015</a>
      <a href="/articles/2014" class="year">2014</a>
      <a href="/articles/2013" class="year">2013</a>
      <a href="/articles/2012" class="year">2012</a>
      <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2011</a>
      <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2010</a>
      <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2009</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

[EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEEBZG)

Comment: The duplicate show a solution with the given markup unchanged. If you can reorder the items you can drop the `order` rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Reorder the years list (usually it's not difficult)
2. Rotate `.inn-wrap` to 180deg
3. Rotate each children of `.inn-wrap` to 180deg

I've added resizable container to check the responsiveness.

```css
#resize {width:340px; padding:20px; border:solid 1px; resize:both; overflow:auto}


.wrap {
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.inn-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}

.inn-wrap > a {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}

.year {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="resize">Resize me!

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inn-wrap">
    <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2009</a>
    <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2010</a>
    <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2011</a>
    <a href="/articles/2012" class="year">2012</a>
    <a href="/articles/2013" class="year">2013</a>
    <a href="/articles/2014" class="year">2014</a>
    <a href="/articles/2015" class="year">2015</a>
    <a href="/articles/2016" class="year">2016</a>
    <a href="/articles/2017" class="year">2017</a>
    <a href="/articles/2018" class="year">2018</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

BTW, if you do not use `class="year"` anywhere else you might get rid of it. And the wrappers look excessive to me also.

## Update

The solution above is a little bit hacky as I used `transform` to fake the appearance of elements instead of the real change of their flex properties.

The more correct and 'fair' solution would be:

1. Reorder the years list
2. Reverse the `flex-flow` of `.inn-wrap`

```css
#resize {width:340px; padding:20px; border:solid 1px; resize:both; overflow:auto}


.wrap {
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.inn-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:row-reverse wrap-reverse;
}

.inn-wrap > a {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.year {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="resize">Resize me!

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inn-wrap">
    <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2009</a>
    <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2010</a>
    <a href="/articles/2011" class="year">2011</a>
    <a href="/articles/2012" class="year">2012</a>
    <a href="/articles/2013" class="year">2013</a>
    <a href="/articles/2014" class="year">2014</a>
    <a href="/articles/2015" class="year">2015</a>
    <a href="/articles/2016" class="year">2016</a>
    <a href="/articles/2017" class="year">2017</a>
    <a href="/articles/2018" class="year">2018</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is responsive in nature, what will happen if it has 3 items or 4 items in first row. this is what is making it challenging

Comment: @Learning, Sorry, did not understand your comment. Please elaborate.

Comment: with your css it will always work for first two items in first row, what if it show 3 items or 4 items based on the width of it parent wrapper, I have added few more example. regarding responsive yes this is part of bootstrap so width of this `wrap ` is not fixed

Comment: @Learning, thanks for the clarifications! I've updated my answer.

Comment: I will accept this as answer, even though i can change the order of year in Ascending order, but it would have been great to make it work as it was

Comment: @Learning, thank you. I've updated my answer again with a more 'clean' solution. However it requires the reorder of HTML anyway.